# Boundaries on double integral help

Tags: calculus, integration

New to double integrals I'm not understanding how to apply the domain on this so I can solve.

$\iint_D \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \ln(x^2+y^2)\ dA$

$D=\{(x,y)\ |\ x>0, y>0, \text{ and } 1<x^2+y^2<2\}$

Comment: How about converting to polar coordinates? Keep in mind that the polar angle ranges from 0 to pi/2.

Comment: I've not converted to polar coordinates like this before. Looking into it.

Comment: Draw the region D and then look at what is the relevant area of interest. Then simply convert it to polar coordinates. And don't forget to convert the area element also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
\iint \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2} +y^{2}}}\ln\left( x^{2} +y^{2}\right) dxdy\\
Convert\ ot\ polar\ coordinates,\ \\
x=r\cos \theta \\
y=r\sin \theta \\
The\ given\ intgeral\ then\ becomes\\
I=\iint \frac{r\cos \theta }{r^{2}} \cdotp \ln\left( r^{2}\right) \cdotp rdrd\theta \\
where\ 1< r< \sqrt{2}\\
0< \theta < \frac{\pi }{2}\\
I=\left(\int ^{\sqrt{2}}_{1} 2\ln rdr\right)\left(\int ^{\frac{\pi }{2}}_{0}\cos \theta d\theta \right)
\end{gather*}

Can you solve these two integrals and complete the answer?

Comment: yes, those integrals I can solve. Was unsure how to bound the double. Now I know how to convert to polar. Thank you!